# There is a way to identify font type in an Android app? (Python, Appium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, appium, android, android-automation

Here is the deal: i'm testing an android app and the client wants us to test font types, sizes and colors.

Using Appium's explorer i'm able to see the objects properties (such us: text, enabled, etc) but the css properties like font-style, font-family aren't visible for me.

There is a way get these properties, given only the object that i need to test?

Comment: Rather than checking these properties individually with specific asserts, have you thought about visual testing? Or does the client not want this?

Comment: The real question you should ask is does client want to know that this looks ok, or do client wants to know if application is using font Tahoma size 13? I don't think that knowing type of font and size will tell client anything useful.

Comment: @beatngu13 i thought about that, the issue will be that for every instance of the app i should take a screenshot, divide the different parts with text on in and analyzing them one by one... and they didn't like that approach :(

Comment: @MichalDobrzycki no, he wants to ensurence that Tahoma 13 is applied in every text, Tahoma 20 Bold in every title, and so on... because they already have guaranteed that with that styles it will fit with the screen's size